# Why does a graph have a vertex of degree at least $\lfloor \frac{2|E|}{n} \rfloor$ and at most $\lceil \frac{2|E|}{n} \rceil$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I want to show that a simple graph has a vertex of degree at least  $\lfloor \frac{2|E|}{n} \rfloor$ and at most $\lceil \frac{2|E|}{n} \rceil$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.

I was trying to find a way to do this with pigeonhole principle or in a different combinatoric way, but I haven't been able to. I have drawn out examples and see that this works, but I can't really come up with a rigorous way to show this.

Can anyone offer some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $2|E|$ is the sum of the degrees of the vertices, so $\frac{2|E|}n$ is the average vertex degree. If $n$ real numbers have average $\alpha$, can all $n$ be less than $\alpha$? Can all $n$ be greater than $\alpha$?

Comment: Well, if the graph was regular then all of the degrees would be the same so every vertex will have degree $\alpha = \lfloor \frac{2|E|}{n} \rfloor$. So its possible that all $n = \alpha$. If the graph wasn't regular, then by definition of average there must be some vertices with degree $<$ and $>$ the average $\alpha$. I'm not quite seeing why this implies the smallest degree is exactly $ \lfloor \frac{2|E|}{n} \rfloor$ though. I'm sure the answer is starting at my face right now

Comment: @callkmo: It doesn’t imply that the smallest degree is exactly $\left\lfloor\frac{2|E|}n\right\rfloor$, but that’s not what you’re asked to show. You’re to show that there must be at least one vertex $v$ such that $\deg v\ge\left\lfloor\frac{2|E|}n\right\rfloor$ and at least one vertex $v$ such that $\deg v\le\left\lceil\frac{2|E|}n\right\rceil$. All you need is the observation in your comment plus the fact that the degree of a vertex is always an integer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks :)

Comment: @callkmo: You’re welcome.